# pip package not found- Windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, pip

[image]

as you can see from the photo attached im using Windows 7 and im trying to run the "mkdocs" package i just installed in the virtualenv but i keep getting the error "...not recognized as an internal or external command..." but the package "mkdocs" is listed as installed by pip and its a little frustrating.

I checked my PATH variable and they are pointing to the correct python versin "2.7"

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the `mkdocs` added to your path, like `pip` was?

Comment: Im not sure i understand? mkdocs is a pip package that im trying to run but apparently its not a "command"

Answer (score 1):

I just tested mkdocs on my windows system and couldn't get it to work.

Running python 3.4, installed in `c:\python34`.

mkdocs is located in `c:\python34\scripts`. Calling `python mkdocs` results in

```
File "mkdocs", line 32
    print 'mkdocs [build|serve] {options}'
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The mkdocs Project roadmap https://github.com/tomchristie/mkdocs/wiki
notes: "Ideally a future version of MkDocs should include Mac and Windows
installers."

Comment: This specific error is most likely due to mkdocs not supporting Python 3 at the time of your post. Starting with v0.10 and up (out in october 2014), mkdocs fully support python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

`mkdocs` prior to v0.10 did not create any windows command in `<python_install>\Scripts`.
If you upgrade to `mkdocs` v0.10+ it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I installed using pip, but with --user flag.  Uninstalled, then re-installed globally (on Linux) worked fine.